Translation notes for different versions of the Bible?
I was looking at the Greek of 1 John 3:12 - and I noticed how different versions translate the passage differently. Some say that Cain murdered his brother, while others state that he killed / slew his brother. While the Greek permits all of these - choosing to call Cain a “murderer” instead of a “killer” or “man slaughterer” has implications for how we interpret Gen 4.
Personally I would argue that Cain was judged like a man slaughterer and not as a murderer (which the Law demands death for); see Numbers 35.
The translators are thus pushing an interpretation of Gen 4 on us as if as though the author of James was giving us this interpretation. While it maybe justified, I currently don’t see how.
Examples of versions that say Cain murdered his brother include the NASB and the NIV. On the other hand, the KJV says that Cain slew his brother.
To help me settle the matter, I would like to know why the translator’s of the NASB and NIV (among others) gave us the translation they did. Is there a good resource or set of resources that can give us insight into translation decisions that were made for select passages by various versions of scripture?

The law was not given yet when Cain killed Able

Note that there has been semantic drift in the terms.  In the time of the KJV, "murder" meant what we would call "assassinate"; "kill" meant "murder"; and "slay" meant "kill."

@Kristopher They ate of the fruit of knowledge - which represents the Law - and knew good and evil. At any rate, it was God who judged Cain - not a human judge. So there’s no issue with interpreting the passage in light of the Law if we assume that God is consistent in his judgement. Rather, it would be more problematic to argue that God was using a different standard to judge Cain - showing him mercy despite never owning up to or repenting of his actions.
